# Using VSTS web transformations with third party web services

Tags: msdeploy, web-config-transform

I am trying to implement the web transformations in VSTS.  Is there a way to add third party web services to my parameters and setparameters xml files?

Answer (score 1):

You can add elements to config file through parameters.xml:

Config xml file:

```
<books>
  <book name="book1" author="author1" />
  <book name="book2" author="author2" />
</books>
```

parameters.xml:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="MyTestParam" description="My Test Param" defaultValue="&lt;price /&gt;">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="books\.xml" match="//book[@name='book1']" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

Then it will add new `price` element after transforming.

Related articles: [Web Deploy XML File Parameterization](https://blogs.iis.net/elliotth/web-deploy-xml-file-parameterization)

[Use Web Deploy Parameters in a Web Deployment Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110).aspx#Using%20Deployment%20Parameters%20for%20Web.Config%20File%20Settings)